# why is the iframe not editable?

Tags: javascript, html

I call two properties:

```
console.log(iframe_textarea.textContent);
console.log(iframe_textarea.isContentEditable);
```

and the result is as expected: "hello" and true. However, the text "hello" does not show up in the iframe, and I cannot insert text to iframe. Another thing to notice is that it works fine when I turn on design mode. So what is wrong here?

```
<iframe id="iframe_textarea" src="iframe.php"></iframe>


<script>
iframe_textarea = document.getElementById('iframe_textarea');

iframe_textarea.contentEditable = true;
iframe_textarea.textContent = "hello";
</script>
```

Comment: I think only `TextNode`s can have `.textContent`. Does it work if you add a `TextNode`?

Comment: You need to access it correctly. `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML= "help"; `

Answer (score 0):

To edit an iframe you must access the iframe body correctly, thus what you have done is added the attribute `textContent` with a value of "hello".

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var frameContent = (frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument);
var frameBody = frameContent.body;
frameBody.innerHTML = " hello";
```

By making the iframe editable you have the option to write in the body now.

Hope this helps